# Не отображаются фото на лендинге

Tags: css

http://asvpage.ru

В чем может быть причина того что фото на лендинге не отображаются? Вроде код проверил, путь правильно стоит, помогите пожалуйста, идей никаких

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это реклама, а не вопрос...

Comment: какая реклама? что не видно что фото на ленде не показываются если их выводить через html img

Comment: Очевидно, проблема в том, что фото не существует

Comment: тоже так подумал, но все фото есть и путь правильный

Comment: @АлексейСоколов а сервер говорит, что по тем путям, куда указывают img, никаких фото нет и не было. Серверу я верю больше, чем вам

Comment: Вот народу тут делать нечего, как гадать... Какое фото не видно...

Comment: Не знаю как у кого... У меня все показывает...

Comment: Потому что ваш сервер отдаёт ответ 404 Not found

Comment: Забудьте про html, добейтесь для начала, чтобы картинка загружалась по прямой ссылке в отдельной вкладке: http://asvpage.ru/images/pasted-image-158.jpg

Comment: @Air Файлы существуют в devtools директории посмотри. А вообще странно у меня при разрешении 300 все картинки отображаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все я понял у вас все изображения обернуты в невалидный тэг picture - просто замените его на div не трогая больше ничего и будет вам счастье;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<picture class="img-5">
<source srcset="images/pasted-image-150.jpg 1x, images/pasted-image-300.jpg 2x" media="(max-width:479px)">
<source srcset="images/pasted-image-225.jpg 1x, images/pasted-image-450.jpg 2x" media="(max-width:767px)">
<source srcset="images/pasted-image-98.jpg 1x, images/pasted-image-196.jpg 2x" media="(max-width:959px)">
<source srcset="images/pasted-image-123.jpg 1x, images/pasted-image-246.jpg 2x" media="(min-width:960px)">
<img src="images/pasted-image-150.jpg" alt="" class="js-3 img-4">
</picture>
```

Не существует картинок, которые указаны в source.
Открой консоль и перейди на вкладку Network выбери img и перезагрузи страницу.